# GWT load TreeItem from server by AJAX

Tags: gwt

I'm working on GWT application with Tree which should load TreeItem from server (i guess by 
AJAX), but i don't know how to setup root element that it will contain "+" for expand on which I should load data from server.
Or possible, Am I going on wrong way and i should use some other mechanism?

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a blank child for undiscovered nodes and remove them when you successfully receive data from the server.

```
TreeItem<MyObject> treeItm = new TreeItem<MyObject>();
treeItm.setText("First Node");
treeItm.addTextItem("");
```

Fire a server call whenever `OpenEvent` is fired for your `Tree`. On success you can remove your child and add data to your tree node (if the data is non-empty).

```
if(objLst!=null&&!objLst.isEmpty()){
    treeItm.getChild(0).remove();
    for(SomeObj obj:objLst){
       TreeItem<SomeObj> someObjTreeItm = new TreeItem<SomeObj>();
       someObjTreeItm.setText("Node Text");
       treeItm.addItem(someObjTreeItm);
    }
}else{
    //No data found
}
```

**Update:** 
GWT does not provide a neater approach to do this. You can also go for [FastTree](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/FastTree) if you need a neater way to do it. `FastTree` provides you methods which is probably what you are looking for.